# apache2 cannot redirect non-www to www within virtual host

Tags: tomcat, mod-rewrite, apache2, virtualhost

I have an apache (2.4.6) server in front of tomcat(6). I want that all requests to www.domain.com redirect permanently to domain.com. My current conf is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain.ma
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.ma
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.ma/$1 [R=permanent,L]

DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.ma/htdocs

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /portal /
ProxyPass /portal/index.htm http://127.0.0.1:8080/portal/index.htm

ProxyPass /images !
ExpiresByType image/* A2592000

</VirtualHost>
```

When I request http://domain.ma/, apache doesn't redirect to http://www.domain.ma/, can someone tell me what's wrong in my conf?

Comment: Note that your http_host regex isn't quite correct. if someone manages to point `domain.masite.example.com` to your server, you'd still redirect because you're only matching on the start of the host name, not the entire string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ServerName domain.ma
ServerAlias www.domain.ma 

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.ma [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.ma/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: With "ist" solution i had a small issue : http://domain.ma/path is redirected to http://domain.ma//path : double slash. I correct it by replacing RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.ma/$1 [R=301,L] within RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.ma$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: @user973296 Without **ServerAlias**, Apache will not know that this **VirtualHost** applies to www.domain.ma and domain.ma

Comment: @user973296 I'm sorry, forgot **RewriteBase**

Comment: i would probably name it the other way around. i.e. `ServerName www.domain.ma` `ServerAlias domain.ma`  as `www.` is the primary. - just aesthetics.